# NGINX is giving error when i try to install

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, installation, amazon-linux

I am trying to install nginx in 
Amazon Linux AMI

but when i try to run command

> sudo yum install nginx

error is below

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.14.0-1.el6.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: nginx-1.14.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. Check if you have a file like `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo`.

The [Nginx install instructions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) tell us to create such a file and that it should look like this:

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Those instructions also tell us

> Due to differences between how CentOS, RHEL, and Scientific Linux populate the $releasever variable, it is necessary to manually replace $releasever with either 5 (for 5.x) or 6 (for 6.x), depending upon your OS version.

So you need to replace `$releasever` with the appropriate version of your OS. But when using Amazon Linux AMI (or, in my case, the Azure version), it's not easy to tell what this is.

**I found that `sudo yum install nginx` only worked when I replaced `$releasever` with `7`.** When I used `6` instead, I got the exact error as you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First run `$ sudo yum update -y` and after that try to install, if still facing same issue then try with `$ sudo yum install nginx --skip-broken`

Comment: sudo yum install nginx --skip-broken is giving output like this


Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.14.0-1.el6.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: nginx-1.14.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    nginx-1.14.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 from nginx